# Showing errors returned via API - React Final Form

Tags: reactjs, api, error-handling, jsx, react-final-form

I am trying to display inline errors returned via API, for each invalid field. I am following the Submission Errors example from [here](https://final-form.org/docs/react-final-form/examples/submission-errors) with something like this:

```
const handleSubmit = async (values) => {
  let errors;

  await createProduct(values) // axios.post(...)
    .then((res) => ...)
    .catch((error) => {
      errors = error.response.data.errors;
      console.log(errors); // returns { title: ["can't be blank"] }
    });

  return errors; // returns { title: ["can't be blank"] }
}
```

then my form looks like this:

```
   <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        {({
          submitError,
          handleSubmit,
          ...
        }) => (
          <BSForm onSubmit={handleSubmit}> // BSForm for boostrapform
            {submitError && (
              <div className="error">{submitError}</div> // not showing
            )}
            {console.log(submitError)} // returns 'undefined'
            <TextField
              name="title"
              ...
            />
```

and I am only able to invoke `submitError` if I pass `{[FORM_ERROR]: 'error message'}` instead of returning the `errors` obj.

I'd love to be able to just relay these API errors into corresponding fields' `meta: { error }` props, but I can totally live with `submitError` wrapping API errors.

Comment: You need state instead of variable(error).If you do setState react will rerender the dom and will update error state and code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution 30 seconds after posting. I missed the `meta: { submissionError }` prop in the example.

So the way I am returning errors seems to be correct, the only difference is instead of displaying Field level errors with `meta.error && meta.touched`, I have to add `meta.submitError` like so:

```
(meta.error || meta.submitError) && meta.touched;
```

then to display the error:

```
{(meta.error || meta.submitError) && meta.touched && (
  <span>{meta.error || meta.submitError}</span>
)}
```

Comment: How did you make this `meta: { submissionError }` work? I am trying to achieve the same thing: returning api errors to respective `meta.submitError` for each of the fields in the form. Would you share more code on how you handled the api errors and passed them down onto `meta.submitErrror` for each field?

Comment: @Chaiwa srry, this was a while ago and I don't remember the exact implementation. I am pretty sure this was a Rails api and I believe these were validation errors on `User.create` if that helps at all.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what worked for my use case! In the `submit handler`, I just needed to **resolve** the promise with the **error object** sent by the **api**, then **React-final-form(RFF)** would propagate the `error messages` down to the *individual field states* via the `meta.submitError`.

The other thing to note here is that, the error object that gets resolved should contain matching `object keys or property names` as the ones sent to the server(i.e. field names in `form.values` should match the object keys you `resolve` back when you receive a `submit error`). My `submit handler` finally looked like this:

```
 const submit = (values) => {
    const promise = 'some promise or api call';

    return new Promise(resolve => {
       promise(values))
        .then(response => {
          // ...do whatever
          resolve(true);
        })
        .catch(error =>{
             if (error.validationErrors) {
                resolve({ [FORM_ERROR]: error.validationErrors });
             } else {
                 //Depending on the shape of the error object from the server, destructure it or transform it so the keys match the field names in the form
                 //Example submissionErrors object would look like: {name: "Duplicate name detected", age: "Invalid age"}
                  const submissionErrors = {
                    ...error.data?.errors,
                    ...error.response?.data?.errors,
                   }; 
               // Then finally `resolve` the errorObject back to the form. 
              //This `resolve` is what makes RFF to update the fieldState of the affected fields with `meta.submitError`
             // You can then use `meta.submitError`, from `fieldState` of a given field, to display its `submission error`
               resolve({ ...submissionErrors});
           }
       });
    });
  };
```